# Why can't I put a pointer to const on right hand side of assignment?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, variable-assignment

Why can't I put `const int *cp1`, on the right hand side of an assignment? Please see this sample

```
int x1 = 1;
int x2 = 2;

int *p1 = &x1;
int *p2 = &x2;

const int *cp1 = p1;

p2 = p1;    // Compiles fine

p2 = cp1;   //===> Complilation Error
```

Why do I get error at the indicated location? After all I am not trying to
*change* a constant value, I am only trying to *use* a constant value.

Am I missing something here.

Comment: You cannot just strip it away. What would be the point of consts if you could just remove it and modify the variable.

Answer (score 10):

> After all I am not trying to change a constant value

Implicit conversion from "pointer to const" to "pointer to non-const" is not allowed, because it'll make it possible to change a constant value. Think about the following code:

```
const int x = 1;
const int* cp = &x; // fine
int* p = cp;        // should not be allowed. nor int* p = &x;
*p = 2;             // trying to modify constant (i.e. x) is undefined behaviour
```

BTW: For your sample code, using [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) would be fine since `cp1` is pointing to non-const variable (i.e. `x1`) in fact.

```
p2 = const_cast<int*>(cp1);
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Basically what you are saying is,

Comment: If a pointer wants to keep an object constant, don't point to that object by a pointer that can potentially change it.

Comment: @LaeeqKhan Yes, to keep the constness. If you have to do that, basically means bad design.